# Interface use with GET method

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, get

I want typed the answer of a getter, I realized a `UserResponse` interface

```
export interface UserResponse {
  research: any;
}
```

I call it like this in the getter:

```
@Injectable()
  export class ThreadService {
    constructor(public messageService: MessageService,
                private http: Http) {
     this.http.get<UserResponse>(this.baseUrl).subscribe((data) => {
       console.log(data.research);
     });
   }
 }
```

here is the error :

> ERROR in src/app/thread-service/thread.service.ts (149,5): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Do I need to implement the interface ?

Comment: maybe use `HttpClient` instead of `Http` if you are using an angular version from late oct/2017 (or later - i think it was 4.3 or sth)...
 
 
which line is 149?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this notation

```
this.http.get<UserResponse>(this.baseUrl).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data.research);
});
```

Is the one used with `HttpClient`, not `Http`.  You should keep this notation and use HttpClient, because Http will be deprecated soon.